# List of available overrides in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, ide, overriding

Working with a C++ project with Visual Studio I encountered this issue.

In Class View if you click the class and then in the Properties window you click the Overrides button you will see  the lists of the virtual functions available.

Then you can easily check if an override has already been implemented or add a new one.

But this list seems to work only for special MFC classes, like CWnd, CStatic, etc.

The list is empty for my own classes derived from the "Base Type" that I've implemented. I haven't found how to "mark" or "teach" Visual Studio to recognize my virtual methods.

Is that possible? Or it works only for "Microsoft" classes?

EDIT: My question is about how to have this automatic tool in Microsoft Visual Studio IDE working for my classes and not only for Microsoft

EDiT2: I'm interested in how to automatically add a new method, not only to check if a virtual method has been already overridden

Comment: Is this really on topic for SO? Seems to be purely about the tool, not about code.

Comment: You have the power to override functions without using Microsoft tools or features.  Overriding is not limited to Microsoft methods or functions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Some questions are still off-topic [...]: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**."* Visual Studio is primarily used for programming.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews,  the topic is about how to use this automatic feature available in VisualStudioto override virtual methods. I know I can override methods even with notepad...

Comment: Try Right-clicking on that method and in the Menu the options "Find All References". Some of them will be overrides to the method.

Comment: @segiol Thanks for your suggestion but it covers only half of the problem. I would like also to automatically add a new method. I'm talking with the  Microsoft support to see if there is a solution. I'll report here if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Microsoft says "a custom base class’ virtual functions won’t be shown in Class View’s “Overrides” list. The list of virtual functions of MFC classes, which can be overridden, is hard coded"

Currently they are investigating how much programming effort would be needed to make this a general feature for the next version of Visual Studio.
But since hardly anybody noticed the discrepancy between this feature and its documentation on MSDN the alternative would be to amend the documentation on MSDN accordingly...